# Adding variables together using Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, string, math, variables, function

I am trying to translate this statement into Actionscript:

"Sally is 5 years old. Jenny is 4 years old. The combined age of Sally and Jenny is 9 years."

This is what I have so far:

```
function getAges (sallyAge:Number,jennyAge:Number,combinedAge:Strin g)
{
trace("Sally's Age:" + sallyAge);
trace("Jenny's Age:" + jennyAge);
trace("Combined Age:" + combinedAge);
}
getAges (5,4,"9");
```

It works - but I would like to have it so that the Actionscript is actually doing the math. Would I declare a variable like

```
var combinedAge = sallyAge + jennyAge;
```

? And where would I put it? Thanks in advance for any assistance, I am really new to this.

Answer (score 1):

```
trace("Combined Age:" + (sallyAge + jennyAge));
```

This usually works in all languages. Put math between a '(' and a ')'

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be:

```
trace("Combined Age: " + (sallyAge + jennyAge));
```

or if you wanted to store the result and then print it:

```
var combinedAge:Number = sallyAge + jennyAge;
trace("Combined Age: " + combinedAge);
```

(both of those would replace the line that currently outputs the combined age)